# Subtract elements of 1st array from 2nd AWS Athena

Tags: sql, arrays, amazon-web-services, set, amazon-athena

I have a table with the below schema

```
 test_name, subject_1, subject_2
```

It has entries like

```
  ('A',['a','b','c'],['b','d']),('B',['d','a','b'],['a','b']),etc
```

Now, I wish to perform set subtraction like set(subject_1)-set(subject_2). So, for 'A', output will be ['a','c']. For 'B', ['d'].

Any help !! I tried searching the internet but in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Athena / Presto the sets are based on Array.

```
WITH example_table AS
 (SELECT 'A' AS test_name, ARRAY['a','b','c'] AS subject_1, ARRAY['b','d'] AS subject_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', ARRAY['d','a','b'], ARRAY['a','b'] )

SELECT test_name, 
       array_except(
             subject_1,
             array_intersect(subject_1,subject_2)
       ) AS diff
FROM example_table
```

- The WITH part is used to create the temp table for the main query.
- The *Diff* is a combination of *array_intersect* and *array_except*